# how to get top-k best candidate sequences when using CRF for decoding in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, crf, viterbi, beam-search

[CRF++](http://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) allows us to get marginal probabilities for each tag (a kind of confidece measure for each output tag) and a conditional probably for the output (confidence measure for the entire output).

```
% crf_test -v2 -m model test.data
# 0.478113
Rockwell        NNP     B       B/0.992465      B/0.992465      I/0.00144946    O/0.00608594
International   NNP     I       I/0.979089      B/0.0105273     I/0.979089      O/0.0103833
Corp.           NNP     I       I/0.954883      B/0.00477976    I/0.954883      O/0.040337
's              POS     B       B/0.986396      B/0.986396      I/0.00655976    O/0.00704426
Tulsa           NNP     I       I/0.991966      B/0.00787494    I/0.991966      O/0.00015949
unit            NN      I       I/0.996169      B/0.00283111    I/0.996169      O/0.000999975
..
```

Tensorflow has its own implementation for crf. After training a crf model, we can get the best tag sequence `y` and its unormalized score for each test input sequence `x` through `tf.contrib.crf.viterbi_decode()` or `tf.contrib.crf.crf_decode()`.

However, it's not sufficient for me to get one best sequence. Currently, the top-k best sequences and their corresponding scores are all useful to me. I notice that currently the aforementioned two functions do not provide these informations. Hence, i am wondering is it possible to get the top-k best candidates after minor modifications to tensorflow source code.

1. top-k tag sequences and their corresponding unormalize scores.
2. marginal probabilities for each tag (as CRF++)